# Linking to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables.js, and I'm populating the table with JSON from a PHP file. My current setup is this:

> PHP file generates JSON > JS file initializes table by link to
>   previous PHP file > PHP file displays the graph (with HTML. It's PHP
>   so I can add the header/footer).

The problem with this is that I have 30 graphs. 30 PHP files for JSON + 30 JS files for the initialization and 30 more PHP for displaying the graphs. Now, this is already a ridiculous amount of files for this (in my opinion), but I need to add more tables.

In each of the tables I have now, I'm going to have a new column with a link that passes a value from another column in the same row to the URL. For example, in one of the columns of the Datatable, a value is 1983. The link in the other column would be `/query.php?value=1983`.

What I wanted to do with this is pass this variable to the PHP file that generates the JSON so I can change the query with the variable. This would be the PHP code

```
<?php
 $myServer = "server";
 $myDB = "database";

 $conn = sqlsrv_connect ($myServer, array('Database'=>$myDB));

 $value = $_GET['value'];

 $sql ="SELECT year, value
        FROM database.dbo.table
        WHERE year = $value";

 $data = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql);

 $result = array();   

 do {
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $result[] = $row;   
     }
 } while (sqlsrv_next_result($data));

 $json = json_encode ($result);

 sqlsrv_free_stmt ($data);
 sqlsrv_close ($conn); 
?>
```

This properly generates JSON. However, when the user clicks the link in the table, I want to take them to a new page with a new table in it. However, the way that I have it, the link takes me to the generated JSON. So my solution would be to merge the PHP that generates the JSON and the PHP file that displays the table, like so

```
<?php //Insert the code I posted above ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Included files, title, etc... -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include '../common/header.inc' ?>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="chart" style="clear: both">
                <thead>
            </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="dataTables_empty">There doesn't seem to be anything here!</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <?php include '../common/footer.inc'?>

        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="table.js"></script> <!-- This is the Datatable initialization -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The initialization would be this then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var header = [ // This puts the data in the right column
        { "sTitle": "Year", "mData": "label", "sClass": "center" },
        { "sTitle": "Length", "mData": "value", "sClass": "center" }
    ]

    var oTable = $('#chart').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "query.php", // Loads the JSON script
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "aoColumns": header,

        "sDom": 'T<"clear">Rlfrtip', 
        "oTableTools": { 
            "sSwfPath": "/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons": ["select_all", "select_none",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Export Selected Rows",
                    "aButtons": [
                        {"sExtends": "copy", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1] },
                        { "sExtends": "csv", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1], "bFooter": false },
                        { "sExtends": "xls", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1], "bFooter": false },
                        { "sExtends": "pdf", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1], "bFooter": false },
                    ]
                },
                { "sExtends": "print", "sButtonText": "Print View" }
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that the initialization is reading the JSON **and** the HTML code below it.

So basically what I'm asking, **is there any way to save just the JSON in a variable so I can link to JUST THE JSON in the JS code?** Is this even possible? Are there any better ways of doing this? (that doesn't require crazy PHP scripting, because I don't know much of it).

---

**SOLUTION**: This is my code after John's suggestion. I also had to change `sAjaxSource` to `aaData`. But now it works!

```
<?php
 $myServer = "server";
 $myDB = "database";

 $conn = sqlsrv_connect ($myServer, array('Database'=>$myDB));

 $value = $_GET['value'];

 $sql ="SELECT year, value
        FROM database.dbo.table
        WHERE year = $value";

 $data = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql);

 $result = array();   

 do {
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $result[] = $row;   
     }
 } while (sqlsrv_next_result($data));

 $json = json_encode ($result);

 sqlsrv_free_stmt ($data);
 sqlsrv_close ($conn); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Included files, title, etc... -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include '../common/header.inc' ?>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="chart" style="clear: both">
                <thead>
            </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="dataTables_empty">There doesn't seem to be anything here!</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <?php include '../common/footer.inc'?>

        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javacript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var json = <?php echo $json ?>;
                var header = [ // This puts the data in the right column
                    { "sTitle": "Year", "mData": "label", "sClass": "center" },
                    { "sTitle": "Length", "mData": "value", "sClass": "center" }
                ]

                var oTable = $('#chart').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "aaData": json, // Loads the JSON script
                    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
                    "aoColumns": header,

                    "sDom": 'T<"clear">Rlfrtip', 
                    "oTableTools": { 
                        "sSwfPath": "/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "sRowSelect": "multi",
                        "aButtons": ["select_all", "select_none",
                            {
                                "sExtends": "collection",
                                "sButtonText": "Export Selected Rows",
                                "aButtons": [
                                    {"sExtends": "copy", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1] },
                                    { "sExtends": "csv", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1], "bFooter": false },
                                    { "sExtends": "xls", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1], "bFooter": false },
                                    { "sExtends": "pdf", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [0, 1], "bFooter": false },
                                ]
                            },
                        { "sExtends": "print", "sButtonText": "Print View" }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the script just echoes the json. you need to store it to a javascript variable and then use it.

Comment: Yes, but how do I link the variable to the initialization so I can use it in the Datatable? I updated the code to show it in a variable

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> var json = <?php contents go here?>;</script>`

or even better echo the javascript from the PHP script

Comment: I figured it out with your answer, and changing `sAjaxSource` to `aaData`. Post your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: there you go and glad you figured it out :)

Comment: add your solution as answer, and mark that as best to help out future visitors to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the script just echoes the json. you need to store it to a javascript variable and then use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var json = <?php contents go here?>;
</script>`
```

or even better echo the javascript from the PHP script itself.